# Android studio app not able to parse on phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been developing an application via `Android Studio` for some time and testing it on my phone (`Galaxy S5 Active`) using the `app-debug.apk` file. I would update the `.apk` then send it to my email.

On my phone, I would download and install the app and test it to see how it works.

Recently, however, I get an error:

```
Describe
There is a problem parsing the package.
```

Before, my phone would warn me about installing apps from unknown sources, to which I would just turn off the warning and it would install anyways. It no longer makes it to that point.

The odd thing about this is, other people are able to install the app still. My phone seems to be the only one that no longer wants anything to do with it.

I have looked into other options but none have seemed to fix my issue. I tried using `AndExplorer` to install it, same error. Ive uninstalled the old version. Ive even tried installing a different application that I made quickly to test.

Any thoughts on what the issue is?

Comment: Does your app specify a minSdkVersion higher than your phone's? Why don't you use adb to transfer the app to your phone?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My laptop does not seem to recognize my phone for debugging when i connect it via USB. My apps current versions are set at: compiledSdkVersion 23, minSdkVersion 11. Im not sure how a Galaxy S5, which is last years model, would be too low to run it?

Comment: Hmm, 11 should be fine for the S5, yeah. Then I don't know what could be wrong